# Merge colums of two DataTables in C#.net

Tags: c#, excel, merge, datatable

If `dt1` contains `Column["Item"]` and `dt2` also contains `Column["Item"]` then, `dt3` will have only one `Column["Item"]`. If both of they have "Burger" as an item then overwrite with one and if uncommon then add in a new row.

I've tried to do it with `tabel3.Clone(table1)` and `table3.merge(table2)`. It shows me this:

[image: A:Part 1]

[image: A:Part 2]

Please notice that the common elements of `tb1` and `tb2` is there and all the elements of `tb2`.

But when I'm just using `tb1.merge(tb2)` and `tb3=tb1`, it is viewing me this:
[image: B: Part 1]

[image: B: Part 2]

Notice, all the elements of `tb1` is viewing and both of the table merges but the elements of `tb2` is not viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using linq to query/write?

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920313%28v=office.12%29.aspx

along with lots of questions here on stack overflow.

Comment: If anyone can solve it using datatable, columns, rows etc., it would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might *(not sure but this would be my first guess)* come up because the default behaviour of a Datatable.Merge() method is set to "PreserveChanges".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx

In your code, add the 'false' swith to the merge method and see if that helps..

```
dt3.Clone(dt1);
dt3.Merge(dt2, false);
```

If not, can you copy out that part of the code as an update in your question so we could shine some more light on the coding.
You don't need to copy out the part of the code that has your OleDb Setings as your 2 gridviews are populating, hence those datatables will be correct.

Thanks,

Kevin